# Is there a way to "delay" a job via the REST API

Tags: jenkins

The instant messaging plugin is capable of taking an IM message like, "build XYZ in 10s" and setting the job to run in 10 seconds. It does this via a java API to schedule the job[0].

I'd like to know if there is some magic parameter I can pass on the REST API[1] that will allow me to "delay" a job in the same manner?

thanks.

[0] - https://github.com/jenkinsci/instant-messaging-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/im/bot/BuildCommand.java#L54

[1] - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GET the following URL:

```
http://jenkins/job/jobname/build?delay=4000sec
```

This example will result in a job being started after 4000 seconds.

[image: Screenshot of build queue]

This works with the `buildWithParameters` URL for parameterized jobs as well.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you point me to where you found this? I had no luck greping the code.

Comment: @dan Hover the 'Build Now' link and check what URL it points to. But yeah, should be documented on `/job/jobname/api` but isn't (at least in 1.480 LTS).

Comment: HA, that's what I get for looking at the code and not just looking at the interface. Much appreciated.